# Value of number input form is not a number

Tags: javascript

I created a form, to calculate a price including shippingcost, taxes and something like that.

Why is the value NaN?
Using number inputforms but need to parseFloat()?

My calulation need to be like this:

```
verkaufspreis = einkaufspreis + versandkosten + verpackungskosten + gewinnmarge in % + transaktionsgebuehren + transaktionsgebuehren_flex in % like paypal
```

This looks very very strange for me, but... i don't get it.

Hope you are fine, thanks for a hint.

```js
"use strict"

let einkaufspreis = document.getElementById("einkaufspreis");
let versandkosten = document.getElementById("versandkosten");
let verpackungskosten = document.getElementById("verpackungskosten");
let transaktionsgebuehren = document.getElementById("transaktionsgebuehren");
let transaktionsgebuehren_flex = document.getElementById("transaktionsgebuehren_flex");
let gewinnmarge = document.getElementById("gewinnmarge");

let verkaufspreis = 0;
const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let rohkosten = parseFloat(verpackungskosten.value) + parseFloat(einkaufspreis.value) + parseFloat(versandkosten.value);

    let preis_mit_marge = (rohkosten / 100 * parseFloat(gewinnmarge.value)) + rohkosten;

    let preis_mit_transaktionskosten = (preis_mit_marge / 100 * transaktionsgebuehren_flex) + preis_mit_marge;

    let endkunden_preis = preis_mit_transaktionskosten;

    console.log(rohkosten, preis_mit_marge, preis_mit_transaktionskosten, endkunden_preis);

})

form.addEventListener("reset", e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <div class="form-group" >
          <label>Einkaufspreis</label> <input id="einkaufspreis" type="number" class="form-control" name="text_name" placeholder="Placeholder Textfeld">
        </div>
      
        <div class="form-group" >
          <label>Versandkosten</label> <input id="versandkosten" type="number" class="form-control" name="text_name" placeholder="Placeholder Textfeld">
        </div>
      
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Transaktionsgebühren Fest</label> <input  id="transaktionsgebuehren" type="number" class="form-control" name="text_name" placeholder="Placeholder Textfeld">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" >
            <label>Transaktionsgebühren %</label> <input id="transaktionsgebuehren_flex" type="number" class="form-control" name="text_name" placeholder="Placeholder Textfeld">
          </div>
      
        <div class="form-group" >
          <label>Verpackungskosten</label> <input id="verpackungskosten" type="number" class="form-control" name="text_name" placeholder="Placeholder Textfeld">
        </div>
      
        <div class="form-group" id="gewinnmarge">
          <label>Gewinnmarge</label> <input id="gewinnmarge" type="number" class="form-control" name="text_name" placeholder="Marge">

          </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="berechnen_button" value="Berechnen">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" name="reset_button" value="Reset">
          </div>

      </form>

      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear which value is NaN?

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of the `<input>` elements? (Have you tried *anything* to find the problem?)

Comment: element.value returns string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully, you mistalkenly assigned id to div element as well, so first it finds this element, which has no value property

```
<div class="form-group" id="gewinnmarge">
<input id="gewinnmarge">
```

also in formula you attend to element `transaktionsgebuehren_flex`, not to its value

```
let preis_mit_transaktionskosten = (preis_mit_marge / 100 * transaktionsgebuehren_flex) + preis_mit_marge;
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks. Values of rohkosten, preis_mit_marge are fine now. But preis_mit_transaktionskosten, endkunden_preis are still NaN.

Comment: @Gismo1337, i added this case too, please check

Comment: @Gismo1337, all these things you could easily find yourself using debugger or alert

Comment: I need to check it more than twice before wasting your time. thank you. stay safe and have a great year 2021

Answer (score 0):

> Using number inputforms but need to parseFloat()?

Meet `valueAsNumber`. Then you won't need `parseFloat()`. (Of course this doesn't change the validity of the other answer, so fix the bug first)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

> `valueAsNumber`
> double: Returns the value of the element, interpreted as one of the following, in order:
>
> - A time value
> - A number
> - NaN if conversion is impossible

(as a comment above points out, `value` is always a string)